# Android - Honeycomb - Action Bar tabs and fragments

Tags: android

I am creating an app for Android 3.0+ that uses the action bar with tabs for navigation. I have 2 tabs that each load a ListFragment:

```
Tab 1 Tab2
A     B
C     D
```

Where A & C are list items in Tab 1 and B & D are list items in Tab 2.

Currently if you select Tab2 and then item B a new ListFragment is loaded on top of the current list fragment in Tab2. Pressing back takes you back to the original Tab2 contents. However if you don't press back and instead select Tab1 you see Tab1's contents on top of the new content you loaded in Tab 2. So I am guessing there is a better way of doing this. I wanted to use multiple fragments in each Tab to reduce the code complexity in each tab (for instance the onListItemSelected handling). Is there another way to do that without using multiple fragments? I am also trying to just save state but I am not sure how to tell the difference from when the user clicks back (then I would want to restore state) and the user has selected tab 1 and then selects tab 2 again (i would want to restore state).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar struggles with the complexity of fragments and tabs on the Action bar.  It seems to me that android for tablets is still very much in its infancy and there are various issues (like yours and the issues I'm having) that will be addressed in the coming months.  For now, I think you just have to handle some of those complexities yourself instead of relying on the Android framework.

To answer your first question more directly, I think you need to step back and think out the functionality before diving into the code.  I can give you a potential solution (keep track of your fragments manually in the activity and simply add and remove fragment as necessary via the ActionBar.TabListener interface.

Also, if you want the user to be switching from one fragment to another like you are suggesting, perhaps the back functionality shouldn't be used.  What happens if the user clicks on the tabs 10 times in a row.  Do you want the back button to take the user back through all of those events?  I think the back button should only be used when the navigation system is very sequential and "back" is an easy concept. Check out all the Google apps that use tabs to see what I'm talking about.